# Body content not showing for nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

For some reason, all body content from all my nodes has suddenly disappeared. It is neither showing up in front- or backende anymore.

I have checked the database, and the content is still present there. It is simply not showing up anymore..

Any ideas?

Comment: welcome to stackOverflow! Please read how to provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try to (temporary) switch to standard Drupal theme. Is your content visible then?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that the **Main Content Block** is enabled? Look at the list at Structure -> Blocks and put the block inside the desired region (mostly the **Content** region).